Keepalived annoying log: interface added/deleted
I'm currently using Keepalived on hosts that also run Docker Engine. Every time I create or stop a container, Docker creates or deletes network interfaces (like veth*). Keepalived logs these events, producing messages like:
Fri Jul 26 10:49:12 2024: Interface vethcd047fe added
Fri Jul 26 10:49:12 2024: Interface veth7ebf4eb added
Fri Jul 26 10:49:13 2024: Interface veth5cca6b7 deleted
Fri Jul 26 10:49:13 2024: Interface vethcd047fe deleted

Is there any way to supress this logs or to make keepalived not to watch those interfaces?
Thanks in advance.

Don't use keepalived on the docker host. These two aren't designed to coexist on the same system. One system (or, better to say, pair of systems) must run keepalived and whatever you want to make highly available with it (load balancer, perhaps), and other set of systems should run "worker" docker nodes with the backends.

Thank you for your answer. Would you explain more about why keepalived and docker are not designed to coexist?

Because both expect to be master of the networking on the host. Docker adjusts it all to it's beliefs of truth: it taunts IP addressing, routing, firewall, creates and destroys virtual NICs at will. When it's alone and the host is dedicated to it, it's all right. And keepalived is a strictly network-oriented software (being a next hop redundancy solution), it wants network to be fully under its control: it constantly sends and receives VRRP messages, it changes addressing. It rightfully complains when something happens with the network it didn't requested, and it's precisely what Docker does.

If you are running this on a host that is using a recent syslog daemon then you should be able to filter these entries out regardless of if the application making them supports suppressing them.
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/configuration/filters.html
https://manpages.org/syslog-ngconf/5
If your system supports rsyslog then it should be possible to add a filter rule along the lines of:
:msg, regex, "Interface veth([a-f]|[0-9]){7} (added|deleted)"

This will match using regex on a string containing "Interface veth" followed by a 7 char hexadecimal value and either the word added OR deleted.
If that doesn't behave then you could also try:
:msg, regex, "Interface veth.*"

OR
:msg, regex, "Interface veth.* (added|deleted)"

You can use https://regex101.com/ to check out the behavior of the regex strings in these and compare with the log strings to see how they work and can adjust them as needed to test.
Regex can sometimes be picky, but with a little tinkering it should do the trick.
